# Django - get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django

I was trying to make an API using REST Framework for uploading a file to the server and my codes are below.

If you have any other easy method to do the same please post your code.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class FileUploader(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) #name is filename without extension
    version = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='uploaded_files')
    size = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class FileUploaderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=FileUploader
        fields='__all__'
        read_only_fields = '__all__'
    def validate(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['owner'] = self.context['request'].user
        validated_data['name'] = os.path.splitext(validated_data['file'].name)[0]
        validated_data['size'] = validated_data['file'].size
        return validated_data
    def create(self,validated_data):
        return FileUploader.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

**views.py**

```
class FileUploaderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FileUploaderSerializer
    parser_classes=(MultiPartParser,FormParser)
    def get_queryset(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(FileUploaderViewSet, self).get_queryset(self,request, *args, **kwargs)
        qs = qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        return qs
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from webapp import views
from webapp.views import(
    UserCreateAPIView,
    UserLoginAPIView,
    FileUploaderViewSet,
    )

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'upload', views.FileUploaderViewSet,base_name='file-view')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    #url(r'^upload/$',FileUploaderViewSet.as_view()),

]
```

My requirement is that i need to upload a file to the server and the details of the uploaded file is to be shown.

**This is the error i am getting!**

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/
>
> Django Version: 1.11.7 Python Version: 3.6.3 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'rest_framework',  'webapp'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py"
>   in wrapped_view
>     58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py" in
>   view
>     90.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in
>   dispatch
>     489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in
>   handle_exception
>     449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in
>   dispatch
>     486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in list
>     40.         queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /upload/ Exception Value: get_queryset()
>   missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Updated **views.py** file as follows

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.status import HTTP_200_OK,HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
from .models import employees
from .serializers import (
    employeesSerializer,
    FileUploaderSerializer,
    )
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.generics import (
    CreateAPIView,
    DestroyAPIView,
    ListAPIView,
    RetrieveAPIView,
    RetrieveUpdateAPIView,
    )

from rest_framework.permissions import(
    AllowAny,
    IsAuthenticated,
    IsAdminUser,
    IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
    )

class employeeList(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        employees1=employees.objects.all()
        serializer=employeesSerializer(employees1,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def post(self):
        pass

User=get_user_model()

from .serializers import(
    UserCreateSerializer,
    UserLoginSerializer,
    )

class UserCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class=UserCreateSerializer
    queryset=User.objects.all()


class UserLoginAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes=[AllowAny]
    serializer_class=UserLoginSerializer
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        data=request.data
        serializer=UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_data=serializer.data
            return Response(new_data,status=HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class FileUploaderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FileUploaderSerializer
    parser_classes=(MultiPartParser,FormParser)

 # overriding default query set
    #queryset = LayerFile.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(FileUploaderViewSet, self).get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs)
        qs = qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        return qs
```

**Traceback:**

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/
>
> Django Version: 1.11.7 Python Version: 3.6.3 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'rest_framework',  'webapp'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py"
>   in wrapped_view
>     58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py" in
>   view
>     90.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in
>   dispatch
>     489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in
>   handle_exception
>     449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in
>   dispatch
>     486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in list
>     40.         queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
>
> File "F:\proj\env\myproject\webapp\views.py" in get_queryset
>     74.         qs = super(FileUploaderViewSet, self).get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /upload/ Exception Value: get_queryset()
>   takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

---

**New Traceback after changeing get query set**

```
class FileUploaderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FileUploaderSerializer
    parser_classes=(MultiPartParser,FormParser)

 # overriding default query set

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(FileUploaderViewSet, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        return qs
```

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/
>
> Django Version: 1.11.7 Python Version: 3.6.3 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'rest_framework',  'webapp'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in
>   _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py"
>   in wrapped_view
>     58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py" in
>   view
>     90.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in
>   dispatch
>     489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in
>   handle_exception
>     449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in
>   dispatch
>     486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py" in list
>     40.         queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
>
> File "F:\proj\env\myproject\webapp\views.py" in get_queryset
>     74.         qs = super(FileUploaderViewSet, self).get_queryset()
>
> File "F:\proj\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py" in
>   get_queryset
>     68.             % self.**class**.**name**
>
> Exception Type: AssertionError at /upload/ Exception Value:
>   'FileUploaderViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or
>   override the `get_queryset()` method.

Comment: Did you try adding a model field in your view as per my updated question?
Where are you stuck now?

Comment: Thankyou..actually i forget to import the model , and that made all the troubles... the issue with the file upload is fixed,now can you help me to extract the name of the file that is uploaded using validated_data

Comment: See if this article helps you. https://medium.com/@jxstanford/django-rest-framework-file-upload-e4bc8de669c0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sayse said, it only requires `self`. but you don't have to pass `self` to `get_queryset()`. `self` is just an instance, `super` itself is self-instance.

So just change your following line from

```
super(FileUploaderViewSet, self).get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

to

```
super(FileUploaderViewSet, self).get_queryset()
```

[look at the code snippet here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset)

**Update:**

Are you sure, your `get_queryset` is in the same class?

Did you try just writing `queryset = Model.objects.all()`?

I do not see `model = ModelName` in your view.

`view class` should have following fields.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return queryset

serializer_class = SerializerClass
model = ModelName
```

Comment: without traceback, won't be able to help

Comment: Exception Type: AssertionError
Exception Value: 
'FileUploaderViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.

Comment: change `def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):` to  `def get_queryset(self):`

Comment: new traceback and code added at the end! please check

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

[`get_queryset`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself) only requires `self` as a parameter.

Simply remove the other args.

Comment: tried removing other tags,but doesnt show any change in the error!

Comment: @AravindMNair - You didn't remove the args in the call to the `super.get_queryset`.

Answer (score 2):

`get_queryset` does not expect the request parameter, and it will not be passed by the DRF base class. It is however available as an instance attribute. You should remove it from the method signature and the super call, and access it via `self.request`.

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = super(FileUploaderViewSet, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    qs = qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)
    return qs
```

Comment: tried ,but it didnt work for me..still the same error!

Comment: @DanielRoseman I think we don't need a 'self' in super() calls get_queryset().

Comment: '' object has no attribute 'request' - is the error message I get here

Answer (score 0):

The get_queryset() does not expect a 'request'. Maybe remove the 'request' argument from the get_queryset(). For reference you can check:
[get_queryset()](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself)

Maybe something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = your_model.objects.all()
    qs = qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)
    return qs
```

Comment: After removing the request argument you are getting the same error? You sure you removed the 'request' from super() call as well as the the get_queryset() params?Maybe could you post the updated code?. Have edited my answer, maybe something like that.

Comment: saw that. I think you still havent removed the 'self' from the super call, I think you need to remove that. Maybe try pasting the above code snippet, and let me know your progress.

Comment: New traceback and get_queryset code snippet added at the end. please check.

Comment: Are you sure that the get_queryset() is placed inside the FileUploaderViewSet? Is it properly indented? Please confirm that.

Comment: [link] (https://i.imgur.com/ECtn7ab.png) Please check this link . Screenshot of the code fragment is attached.

Comment: Could you try removing the super call()? See if that works. I think you dont need a super call here since you are constructing the queryset on your own. I have updated my answer.