# Get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django

I have a listview like this:

```
class IncidentListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Incident
    paginate_by = 3


    def get_queryset(self,request):
        order_by = request.GET.get('order_by', 'defaultOrderField')
        return model.objects.all().order_by(order_by)
```

When I go to the url, I get this error:

```
get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to make it so you can click a sorting link that creates a new listview, but unsure how to approach.

For reference, I followed the recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509515/django-get-queryset-missing-1-required-positional-argument-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
class IncidentListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Incident
    paginate_by = 3


    def get_queryset(self):
        order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by', 'defaultOrderField')
        return model.objects.all().order_by(order_by)
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I realize that paginate does not work well with this solution... do you know how to pass the request via paginate link?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This simply returns a queryset of all model objects. The pagination is handled by the ListView, namely the `paginate_by = 3` part. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

In class-based views, you can always refer to the request via `self.request`. But in order to keep all the other magic like pagination working, you should not completely replace the `get_queryset` method. It is better to override the dedicated hook [`get_ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_ordering) instead. It should return a string or tuple of strings that will be accepted by the model's queryset's `order_by`:

```
class IncidentListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Incident
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_ordering(self):
        return self.request.GET.get('order_by', 'defaultOrderField')
```